# Programmatically enabling/disabling screen rotations in Android

Tags: android, preferences, screen-orientation

I have an app which displays a large amount of text for the user to read.

I've found that when reading while lying down, I get annoyed that the screen rotates even though my head and the screen are aligned.

I do not want to set this to be permanently in portrait mode, so I think this would preclude an approach of setting the

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in the manifest.

Ideally, I would like to enable/disable automatic orientation changes via a preference page.

What would be my best approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would do this by having my preference page write to the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for my application, then reading this value and calling [Activity.setRequestedOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) from the code when the text view in question is loaded or displayed.

For example:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("fix_orientation_to_portrait", false)) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
```

This can be in either the `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method. The only reason not to have it in the `onCreate()` method is if the changing of the setting happens in this activity, or on a child activity that will come back to this one when it is done.

**Edit:**

OK, if that doesn't work (and I am not really sure it will), maybe you could try having two different layout xml files - one with the screenOrientation set, and the other without. When you load your Activity/View, you can dynamically load one or the other based on your saved preferences. It's <strike>nasty</strike> not clean, but it should work.

Comment: I'm sure you tried it, but out of curiosity - why does it not work? I would have expected that calling setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) is effectively the same as adding the line you mentioned in your question. (And there's SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR).

Comment: I didn't try it - it's a big PITA to set up a new project and do this stuff... I'm just doing some end-of-day StackOverflow whoring. I'm going on jamesh's word that it didn't work, but now that you mention it, he was speaking in the hypothetical. Editing accordingly...

Comment: Your first approach worked. I've added some code to illustrate. Thanks

Comment: Almost 4 years later but I wanted to add for others who end up here that you can lock the current orientation with setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED). I tried setting NONSENSOR but it restored portrait (app default?) before locking if I was in landscape mode. Tested on KitKat.

Answer (score 2):

Add This line inside onCreate() Function. It is working ...

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```