# Android: Efficient Screen Rotation Handling

Tags: android, rotation, screen, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

In Android, when the screen orientation changes (between landscape and portrait) the `onCreate` method is called which ,if not handled properly, will recreate the entire activity when the result is too simply change the layout and retain all of the same information.

I know of a few ways to solve this, but I'm interested in the most efficient way.

1) Telling the manifest that I will handle the orientation change by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method and leaving it empty.

2) override `onSaveInstanceState()` and save the data here to be repopulated in `onCreate()`

3) Override `onPause()` which will create a bundle of the data and send it to `onSaveInstanceState()`

Obviously, these are all options, but which one is a better practice (small, medium, large amounts of data)

Thank you

Comment: One way is you can stop the re-creation of Activity and just switch between portrait and landscape layout. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749675/how-to-stop-changing-the-orientation-when-a-progress-bar-is-spinning-in-android/7749727#7749727)

Comment: While this way seems to work nicely, I want to be able to make use of the auto-change in layouts by using the `res/layout-land` folder. Unless of course it is too much overhead for a simple activity.

Comment: Well, this will auto-matically change its layout, you just need to change the contentview in the code thats it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (`onDestroy()` is called, followed by `onCreate()`).

- To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity
  restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in
  which Android calls `onSaveInstanceState()` before it destroys your
  activity so that you can save data about the application state. You
  can then restore the state during `onCreate()` or
  `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

**However, you might encounter a situation in which restarting your application and restoring significant amounts of data can be costly and create a poor user experience. In such a situation, you have two other options:**

1. [Retain an object during a configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

   Allow your activity to restart when a configuration changes, but carry a stateful Object to the new instance of your activity.
2. [Handle the configuration change yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

   Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain configuration changes, but receive a callback when the configurations do change, so that you can manually update your activity as necessary.

So, As per your data operation and coast of user experience with application you can choose what is best for you..

**EDIT:** As per your need for just change the layout I think you have to use  `onConfigurationChanged()` and do the changes in it.

Comment: How does this apply to fragments?

Answer (score 0):

```
//by changing the orientation if your layout not disturb in design just data destroyed
 //then use the below attribute in manifest in activity you want to do


   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"

//but your whole screen design disturb then turn off orientation by using this

  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```