# Android layout configChanges

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I created layout and layout-land folders, in Manifest i have

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

If i remove the `android:configChanges` from the **Manifest** I can see the layout change from portrait to landscape...the problem is that the previous screens are destroyed when trying to go back.

I am assuming i could add some code in my Java to tell it when to change layouts. I have read a bunch of posts already but am confused where in the code it would happen.

I am trying to use some prepackaged code because I am new to Android. The link below is the Java code for the menu screen in particular i need to change layouts for. thanks so much!!

[menu Java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/menuSimpleAdvanced.txt)

Comment: how did you start the previous activities (which I assume are the screens you refer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` will stop re-creation of your Activity and also prevent from changing the layout to layout-land/portrait layout. In that case you have to manage it manually from the java code. If you `don't` want your `Activity` to get `re-created` when you rotate your device/ change orientation. What you can do is just change the layout when your screen orientation changes inside **onConfigurationChanged()** method,

Check my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749675/how-to-stop-changing-the-orientation-when-a-progress-bar-is-spinning-in-android/7749727#7749727), how can that be done.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I believe this is what I want."What you can do is just change the layout when your screen orientation changes inside onConfigurationChanged() method,"  Still confused where it fits in my code?

Answer (score 2):

My work around for these problem was

in manifeast file you can use android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  if you wont these line then activity will be destroyed and created again.

and we have a below method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname);
}
```

here you can handle the orientation  change...

Comment: simply copy paste of my answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me where in my code this would go? thanks so much! Very new and trying :)

Comment: @Lalit Poptani happy to hear from you but coincidently we both had same thing in mind to solve the issue

Comment: @Agarwal might be but I almost had it when you where to answer yet, difference shows 3-4 minutes. ;)

Comment: Just confused where this method goes in my code? sorry for the lack of knowledge :(

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable onConfigurationChanged is what I am getting? thanks for sticking with me :)

Comment: here is the link to my original code, can u please tell me where to paste your code...thanks, really really appreciate http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/menuSimpleAdvanced.txt

Comment: what is BT_activity_base.  i think you must paste it just before you onStrat() Method.

Comment: Screen goes black on rotation

Comment: Here is link to Manifest if that helps? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/Manifest.txt

Comment: here is link to BT_activity_base file, awesome if this can get figured out, thanks so so much :) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/Activity_base.txt